# How to Calculate stopover time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the stopover time of bikeshare usage (basically how long are bikes sitting for unused) in excel. I have time stamp data of bikes with their duration of trips. I can calculate the stopover time manually for each bike ID individually, but that would take for ever.

Here's a sample of what the data looks like:

[image]

The formula I'm applying is =(C2-B3)*1440 and applying that to 1 Bike ID, but when the Bike ID changes as you see highlighted I run into an issue with applying this formula.

How can I write a formula in excel when the BIKE ID changes to a new bike ID to not incorporate the previous Bike ID time with the "current"

Comment: You can use an IF `if(H3=H2,C2-B3*1440,"")`  This formula would go in row 3 and be filled down.  The formula just checks if the bike ID above is the same as the current bike ID before doing the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you start in cell H3 then use

```
=IF(D3=D2,(B3-C2)*1440,"")
```

Then drag that formula down.

If you use C2-B3 then you will always get a negative time.